# django templates not reloading after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am making my first Django application and am running into some AJAX issues. On my website, the user can see a gallery of photos.  To get to this page, they merely need to go to /photos.  The photos view calculates the photos to display and passes them to the template for rendering.

They can request to see more photos by clicking a button.  Clicking this button sends an AJAX request to the server.  The server calculates a new set of photos to display and then once again passes the photos to the same template for display. The only issue is that the photos on screen never change.

I verified that new photos are being calculated by the server.  Unfortunately, lots of things that should happen never actually happen.  First and foremost, using the Chrome developer tools, I can see that the photo files are never sent to the browser from the server.  Furthermore, the DOM never updates the  src attributes to refer to the new photos.  What do I need to be doing to make these things happen?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Some code:

```
#The python view summarized
def photos:
    photoList = GetListOfPhotos() #Returns photo objects.  These objects have a file field which is access from the template.
        return render(request,
              'photos.html', 
             {'photoList': photoList}, 
              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
             )

#AJAX request
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#right-arrow").click(function(event) {
        $.post("/photos/", {"arrow" : "right"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What part? I don't think the back end will be too helpful.  I'll summarize it

Comment: `$.post("/photos/", {"arrow": "right"})` sends the request to the server, but does nothing with the servers response.  You probably want to add a callback when your post succeeds to update your dom and download the new images.

Comment: I was just reading through the jQuery.ajax documentation when this dawned on me. It makes sense that the system would not re-render the entire page. I'll reconfigure my server code to send only images and then use a callback function to populate those in the DOM.  How do I download the images?

Comment: What I typically do is have the server return a snippet of html in response to the post call, then insert that in to the dom using something like: `$('#ajaxoutput').html(post_response);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most suspicious thing to me is that you say

> once again passes the photos to the same template for display.

Is this the EXACT same template your `/photo` url corresponds to?  If it is you should probably be using a small subsection of it just to render the photos in a list or a table (or however you display them)  Other than that there are a couple of things that can help resolve this.

1. In chrome developer tools make sure that your javascript is sending the correct data.  This can be done by verify your params in the net tab, and by liberal use of console log;
2. Verify that your view is in fact doing what it is supposed to.  I like pdb.  It is perfect for this.  You could write tests, or make print statments or w/e.
3. Verify that your front end is recieving data. Chrome tools can help you do this.  The net tab will let you see the response.

I would like to be more specific but you haven't provided specifics.

To help with better answers its important to post all relevant code.

Comment: In the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools, I clicked on the AJAX request and took a look at the html being sent to the browser.  It looks like the new html is 100% correct, including links to the correct photos.  It's bizarre that the browser never makes an attempt to render this html.  You did bring up a good point... I should be using a separate template, or better yet, I should just be sending photos back to the browser and then be using separate JS to apply those photos to the DOM.

Comment: @user1556487 if you read Joe Day's  comment you are not actually doing anything with the response.  What makes you think that the response will be put anywhere? If th js that you posted is your full code then a callback needs to be defined for your ajax request